# How to use data in rows returned from a database in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, database

Using Javascript I need to get some rows from a DB table, and then loop through each row and use different fields from each row.

For example, if I get the rows like this:

```
var coordinatesArray = '<?php
    global $wpdb;
    echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM users_coordinates WHERE lat>20 and lat<40 and long>-10 and long<40);
?>';
```

How should I write the following code:

```
// for each row do: {
//    alert the id field
//    alert the lat field
//    alert the long field
// }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is the way to put the output in, that ensures that the result will be valid JavaScript and protects you from arbitrary code execution in JS.

```
var coordinatesArray = <?php
global $wpdb;
// replace * by id, lat and long since you don't need other fields
$sql = "SELECT id, lat, long FROM users_coordinates WHERE lat>20 and lat<40 and long>-10 and long<40";
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
// if the function fails (?), make valid JS syntax
if (is_array($rows)) {
    echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
    echo '[]';
}
?>;
for (var i=0; i<coordinatesArray; i++) {
    alert(coordinatesArray[i].id);
    alert(coordinatesArray[i].lat);
    alert(coordinatesArray[i]["long"]);
}
```

The other way would be creating a JS object with the `id` field as key of the JS object:

```
var coordinatesMap = <?php
global $wpdb;
// replace * by id, lat and long since you don't need other fields
$sql = "SELECT id, lat, long FROM users_coordinates WHERE lat>20 and lat<40 and long>-10 and long<40";
// note: OBJECT_K, the result will be an associative array with the first field of a
// row as key
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT_K);
// if the function fails (?), make valid JS syntax
if (is_array($rows)) {
    echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
    echo '{}';
}
?>;
for (var id in coordinatesMap) {
    if (coordinatesMap.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        alert(id);
        alert(coordinatesMap[id].lat);
        alert(coordinatesMap[id]["long"]);
    }
}
```

Please replace `alert` by something else, it's not really user-friendly. Remember that PHP != JavaScript and you cannot use PHP functions in JavaScript and vice versa. If you're not sure how the output would look like, use the *View source* option of a page.

References:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Comment: @Lekensteyn, first - thanks! Second - is one of the ways better/faster than the other one?

Comment: @Ash: I find the second cleaner than the former. Both are correct, but if you intend to do a quick id <-> lat/long lookup, the second is the way to go. I just noticed that the field is named `long` which is a keyword reserved for future use. See my edit.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, I implemented your second suggestion in my code successfully but there's one thing I still don't understand - in my sql query I actually use `$sql = "SELECT user_id, ...` and not `$sql = "SELECT id, ...` as I wrote here. But in the for loop you suggested I used the var `id` as you wrote it, and it still works. How does it know to map user_id into id? User_id is not defined as a key in the db although it is unique.

Comment: @Ash: if `user_id` is not unique, do not use the second code as it results in data loss when records with the same `user_id` occur in the result. The `id` as in `id in coordinatesMap` defines a JavaScript variable with the key of `coordinatesMap`, it could be named `the_key_in_coordinatesMap` as well and has nothing to do with the `id` field in the database. The `$wpdb->get_results()` method uses the first field as key if the second argument is set to `OBJECT_K`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, `user_id` is unique so no problem there. I see, OBJECT_K does the trick. I just have to make sure that user_id stays the first field for good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a better time writing your own custom PHP script to fetch these values (rather than depending on WP), loop through them, and build a json object that you return to the javascript.

Answer (score -1):

First, $wpdb->get_var can only get one value. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable

Use $wpdb->get_results instead
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

```
var coordinatesArray = '<?php
    global $wpdb;
    echo $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM users_coordinates WHERE lat>20 and lat<40 and long>-10 and long<40);
?>';

for(coord in coordinatesArray) {
    alert(coordinatesArray[coord].id);
    alert(coordinatesArray[coord].lat);
    alert(coordinatesArray[coord].long);
}
```

I haven't tested, but it should be something like that.

Comment: Won't work, an array is `[]`, not `''`. `echo $wpdb->het_result(...)` gives just `Array`, not the representatation of it.

Comment: @Domenic , can you say how you'd do it?

Comment: @Ash, by using a normal `for (var i = 0; i < coordinatesArray.length; ++i)` loop. `for ... in` is not meant for use with arrays, but instead for use with objects. It will enumerate all `enumerable` properties of the array, including say any that have been added by the Prototype.js framework or any user code that may or may not be under your control.

Comment: Unless you can be sure that an object has no inherited properties you need to put a `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` check as well to see whether a property is inherited or not. But I think that falls outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @Domenic, and then inside the loop how will I address each of the rows and the fields inside of them?

Comment: @Ash, I wasn't really addressing your question, just the abuse of `for ... in`. (Thus commenting instead of answering.) But, Lekenstyn's answer has it covered.

Comment: @Codler, thanks for the answer and the fix on the `get_var`. Probably saved me a lot of debugging time.